# Trying to get the details of the connections to PVS server

Tags: powershell, citrix

I am trying to get an output giving all the connections to my PVS server. I am using powershell to achieve it and did the following :

```
Add-PSSnapIn MCLIpssnapin

#PVS Variables

$pvsservers = "ASPPVS.ASPcloud.com"

$body +=echo "-----------------------------Connections to PVS server-------------------------------"`r`n""`r`n""
foreach ($server in $pvsservers)
    {
    $pvsstatus = Mcli-Get ServerStatus -p servername="$server" | findstr "deviceCount"
    $pvsstatus = $pvsstatus.Replace("deviceCount:","")
    $body +=echo "Current Connections to $server : $pvsstatus

"
    }
Write-Output $body
```

By doing this, I get the following error :

```
Mcli-Get : The specified Server does not exist.
At C:\Users\ctxadmin\Desktop\PVS.ps1:10 char:15
+     $pvsstatus = Mcli-Get ServerStatus -p servername="$server" | findstr "deviceCou ...
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : DeviceError: (:) [Mcli-Get], EAException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidServer,McliPSSnapIn.McliGet

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\ctxadmin\Desktop\PVS.ps1:11 char:2
+     $pvsstatus = $pvsstatus.Replace("deviceCount:","")
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

-----------------------------Connections to PVS server-------------------------------



Current Connections to APNPVS02.Apncloud.com :
```

How do I change my code to get it running successfully?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by ***excluding the domain name***.
I was giving the entire computer name : **$pvsservers = "ASPPVS.ASPcloud.com"**.
Instead, I gave the *computer name*, excluding the domain name as : **ASPPVS**